# Bubble sort on both cols of a 2d array and queue output not transferrred to a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm have 2 issues with the function I had created. First is the bubble sort on 2 cols on a 2d array(Decending sort - 2nd col first, then 1st col) . I believe I've implemented this correct, but the results tend to differ.

> Input
>   COL 1 COL 2
>   35.484%   38.296%
>   1.075%    0.112%
>   1.075%    0.056%
>   48.387%   0.124%
>   1.075%    0.005%
>   2.151%    0.051%
>   2.151%    0.006%
>   2.151%    0.002%
>   3.226%    0.003%
>   1.075%    0.032%
>   1.075%    0.184%
>   1.075%    0.263%
>
> Output
>   35.484%   38.296%
>   48.387%   0.124%
>   1.075%    0.112%
>   2.151%    0.051%
>   2.151%    0.006%
>   1.075%    0.056%
>   3.226%    0.003%
>   1.075%    0.005%
>   1.075%    0.032%
>   1.075%    0.184%
>   2.151%    0.002%
>   1.075%    0.263%

You can see immediately, the last line of the output should have been at somewhere in the higher order.

And I'm unable to output the entire array to a range. No error is shown, the function simply exits. I appreciate any help in this. The code is shown below and thanks again.

```
    Function larger(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)

    Dim Q() As Variant
    Dim x As Range, y As Range
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim varTemp(1 To 2) As Variant



    Q = Range(range1.address, range2.address)
    ReDim Q(1 To UBound(Q, 1), 1 To UBound(Q, 2))

    j = 1
    i = 1
    While i < UBound(Q, 1)
        For Each x In range1
            While j < UBound(Q, 2)
                Q(i, j) = x
                j = j + 1
                Q(i, j) = range2(i)
            Wend

            i = i + 1
            j = 1
        Next
    Wend


 ' Bubble sort  - first with the 2nd col and then the 1st col

 '2nd col
    For i = LBound(Q) To UBound(Q) - 1

            If Q(i, 2) < Q(i + 1, 2) Then

                For j = 1 To 2
                    varTemp(j) = Q(i, j)
                    Q(i, j) = Q(i + 1, j)
                    Q(i + 1, j) = varTemp(j)
                Next j
            End If
        Next

   '1st col
    For i = LBound(Q) To UBound(Q) - 1
          If Q(i, 1) < Q(i + 1, 1) Then
            For j = 1 To 2

                varTemp(j) = Q(i, j)
                Q(i, j) = Q(i + 1, j)
                Q(i + 1, j) = varTemp(j)
            Next j
            End If
        Next



  j = 1
 For i = LBound(Q, 1) To UBound(Q, 1)
    MsgBox (Q(i, j) & " " & Q(i, j + 1))

 Next
    MsgBox ("end")


Range("P3:Q14") = Q         'Not writing entire queue into specified range

End Function
```

Comment: Why bubble sort in the first place? Check out this answer, maybe it'll help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509255/vba-bubble-sort-algorithm-slow/15510304#15510304

Comment: I know this a delayed response, I was stuck at work for another proj. I chose bubble sort as it is easy to implement, and I don't anticipate large data to sort. I'll check out quick sort, I've heard that it is more quicker and efficient algorithm. If you could help with my 2nd issue, I'm unable to transfer the entire array data to a range in the worksheet. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to sort a range, it's easiest to use Excel's build in Sort method! Thus, try this method:

```
Sub SortRange(rng As Range)
    rng.Sort rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1), xlAscending, rng.Resize(, 1)
End Sub
```

You can call it like this: `SortRange Range("A1:B12")`

In case you want to sort it yourself to cater for some specialties, here's the bubble sort:

```
Sub Sort(rng As Range)
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    varValues = rng.Cells

    For i = 1 To UBound(varValues, 1)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(varValues, 1)
            Select Case varValues(i, 2)
                Case Is > varValues(j, 2): subSwap varValues, i, j
                Case varValues(j, 2):
                    If varValues(i, 1) > varValues(j, 1) Then subSwap varValues, i, j
            End Select
        Next j
    Next i

    rng.Cells = varValues
End Sub

Private Sub subSwap(varValues As Variant, i As Long, j As Long)
    Dim varTemp As Variant
    Dim k As Long

    For k = 1 To UBound(varValues, 2)
        varTemp = varValues(i, k)
        varValues(i, k) = varValues(j, k)
        varValues(j, k) = varTemp
    Next
End Sub
```

Looking at your code, I noticed a few things (that's why I remade from scratch instead of "fixing" yours):

- Instead of `Range(range1.address, range2.address)` you can use `Range(range1, range2)`, or event better, declare it as a full range (e.g. Range("A1:B12")` directly. Also, using range1.Resize(,2) will resize to a two column range
- Your whole first loop seems a bit redundant and probably wrong (at least you always assign the value from range1 to all columns). Normally, you can assign a full range to an array using `varArray = YourRange.Cells`. No need to redim.
- In your bubble sort, you need to nest the check for the column to be checked second in the first loop. Else, you can get wrong results when the column to be checked first has more the 2 rows with the same value
- When assigning an array back to a range, better assign to `Range.Cells`. Also, make sure that the range has the same dimension.
- Last but not least, you make your sub flexible, i.e. allow any parameter - but then assign the result to a hard-coded range. This will fail the moment you call it with some other range - or your workbook structure changes! Better flexibilize this, too (e.g. using `Range("NamedRangeName").Resize(UBound(Q, 1), UBound(Q,2)).Cells = Q

Comment: Thanks for this. The code works perfectly, I have modified it to sort in decending order. Your inputs are well received. My first loop will take values from both the ranges - see these 2 stmts  Q(i, j) = x , Q(i,j) = range2(i). I agree the implementation seems a little bizarre when a better one exists (as you have depicted). I appreciate the time and effort taken to build this code from scratch. Thanks again.