# Custom sort routine for unique string A being place after another string B, C, D, etc if string A is found within them

Tags: vba, excel

## Situation

I have a UDF that works with a range that it is passed that is of variable height and 2 columns wide.  The first row will contain text in column 1 and an empty column2. The remainder of column 1 will contain unsorted text with an associated value in the same row in column 2.  I need to sort the data such that if some text in column 1 also appears in some other text in column.

## Problem

My VBA skills are all self taught and mimimal at best.  I remember a few decades ago in university we did bubble sorts and played with pointers, but I no longer remember how we achieved any of that. I do well reading code but creating is another story.

## Objective

I need to generate a sort procedure that will produce unique text towards the bottom of the list.  I'll try wording this another way.  If text in column1 can be found within other text in column, that the original text need to be placed below the other text it can be found in along with its associated data in column 2.  The text is case sensitive. Its not an ascending or descending sort.

I am not sure if its a restriction of the UDF or not, but the list does not need to be written back to excel, it just needs to be available for use in my UDF.

## What I have

```
Public Function myFunk(rng As Range) As Variant

Dim x As Integer
Dim Datarange As Variant
Dim Equation As String
Dim VariablesLength As Integer
Dim Variable As String

Datarange = rng.Value


'insert something around here to get the list "rng or Datarange" sorted
'maybe up or down a line of code depending on how its being done.



Equation = Datarange(1, 1)

For x = 2 To UBound(Datarange, 1)
    VariablesLength = Len(Datarange(x, 1)) - 1
    Variable = Left$(Datarange(x, 1), VariablesLength)
    Equation = Replace$(Equation, Variable, Datarange(x, 2))
Next x

myFunk = rng.Worksheet.Evaluate(Equation)

End Function
```

## Example Data

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated. In that last example I should point out that the "=" is not part of the sort.  I have a routine that strips that off the end of the string.

Comment: Trying to think through this this.  I am not too worried about efficiency as I will probably be dealing with 10 items to be sorted at most.  I am thinking take the first item in the list and searching down the rest of the list.  If it finds something it exists in, then those item swap.  Start the process again.  If the search makes it to the end without a swap move to the second item on the list and repeat until no swaps occur.

Comment: Can you provide additional examples of input and sorted output?  It's not clear to me why the row with a single `a` is not included up with the `adAd` row.  They both contain an `a`.  Is there some minimum number of characters to match?  If so, you can iterate through the characters in chunks of that minimum length (see `MID`) and see if other strings have the same characters in them.

Comment: As long as the text in a given row does not appear in within any of the text in any other row below it, it is sorted for my needs.  There is no minimum from the way I am thinking about it, just what I think of as uniqueness.  The text as a whole cannot appear with any text below it in the sorted list.  I tossed in the "a" and "A" for case sensitivity.

Comment: Technically you can just sort them by length in descending order.  That ensures that an element at the top of the list cannot be contained in an item lower in the list.  Sorting by length recovers your two possible solutions in the top row in the picture.  I think if you want some other result (possibly for aesthetic reasons) then you need to define more specific constraints.  Sorting by length would be a simple modification of a bubble sort.  [See this answer for sorting algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15510304/4288101).

Comment: Interesting approach sorting by length.  I had not thought of that method.  Dont need to worry about case sensitivity that way either. No need for aesthetics as there is no need to put the sorted list back to the spreadsheet.  Its essentially going to be a list of variable being substituted back into an equation.  Substituting the value of Aw before substituting the value of A ensures I do not wind up with 10w (Assuming A had a value of 10).  I had been working on this while waiting for feed back and pointers and came up with something that works...though not necessarily the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to achieve what I was looking for I added a SWAP procedure and changed my code to look like this.

```
Public Function MyFunk(rng As Range) As Variant

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim datarange As Variant
    Dim Equation As String
    Dim VariablesLength As Integer
    Dim Variable As String

    'convert the selected range into an array
    datarange = rng.Value

    'verify selected range is of right shape/size
    If UBound(datarange, 1) < 3 Or UBound(datarange, 2) <> 2 Then
        MyFunk = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'strip the equal sign off the end if its there

    For x = 2 To UBound(datarange, 1)
        If Right$(datarange(x, 1), 1) = "=" Then
            datarange(x, 1) = Left$(datarange(x, 1), Len(datarange(x, 1)) - 1)
        End If
    Next x

    'sort the array so that a variable does not get substituted into another variable
    'do a top down swap and repeat?  Could have sorted by length apparently.

    For x = 2 To UBound(datarange, 1) - 1
        For y = x + 1 To UBound(datarange, 1)
            If InStr(1, datarange(y, 1), datarange(x, 1)) <> 0 Then
                For z = LBound(datarange, 2) To UBound(datarange, 2)
                    Call swap(datarange(y, z), datarange(x, z))
                Next z
                y = UBound(datarange, 1)
                x = x - 1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x

    'Set the Equation
    Equation = datarange(1, 1)

    'Replace the variables in the equation with values
    For x = 2 To UBound(datarange, 1)
        Equation = Replace$(Equation, datarange(x, 1), datarange(x, 2))
    Next x

'rest of function here

End Function

Public Sub swap(A As Variant, B As Variant)
    Dim Temp As Variant
        Temp = A
        A = B
        B = Temp
End Sub
```

I sorted by checking to see if text would substitute into other text in the list.  Byron Wall made a good point that I could have sorted based on text length.  Since I had completed this before I saw the suggestion it did not get implemented though I think it may have been a simpler approach.