# Reordering column headers by name

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to reorder column headers by name, though I'm running into a couple issues. The first is that some column headers are the same (they are like this from the export). The second is that the current code I am using does not seem to arrange all headers properly on the first go around, or some times at all. The third is that it is fairly slow to run.

Code below:

```
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, i As Integer
Dim Found As Range, counter As Integer


arrColOrder = Array("Reporting Status", "CloseRecord", "Tracking Number", "Close Record", "Tracking Number", "Close Record: Only")

counter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

    Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column <> counter Then
            Found.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort?

Comment: Hey @SJR, that's a good question. I didn't know it was possible to sort based on an Array

Comment: Ha, actually I thought you were sorting a range. Search for bubble sort, there are many examples online. e.g. maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509255/vba-bubble-sort-algorithm-slow

Comment: @SJR At first glance, this does not appear be what I want: I have a very specific order that I want the columns in, not alphabetical. If it helps, the array above is only a fraction of the total array. There are 50+ columns to order.

Comment: OK, I may have been a bit hasty. Having had a better look, it looks as though you are sorting a range in an order defined in an array. Is that right? If so, you could add another row with a match formula and then sort on that row?

Comment: Another option is to define a custom sort list.

Comment: @SJR appreciate the help, though I couldn't get it to work how I wanted. Seems like I'd need to spend more time with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, i As Integer, lc As Integer
Dim Found As Range

arrColOrder = Array("Reporting Status", "CloseRecord", "Tracking Number", "Close Record", "Tracking Number", "Close Record: Only")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lc))

For i = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

    Set Found = Rng.Find(arrColOrder(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column = i + 1 Then GoTo Skip
            If Found.Column <> i + 1 Then
                Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                Columns(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, Found.Column + 1), Cells(1, lc))
            End If
    End If
Skip:
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```