# Passing double array to Variant failing

Tags: arrays, vba, excel-2003

On trying to pass the double array to a bubble sort sub i get the error message: "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

If i change the array from Variant to double inside the sub i get rid of the error; however i need to use the same sub for sorting int, double and user defined arrays. I tried using function but no luck. Using Excel 2003 on Windows7.

```
Sub BubbleSort(MyArray() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant
 
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(MyArray)
            If MyArray(i) > MyArray(j) Then
                Temp = MyArray(j)
                MyArray(j) = MyArray(i)
                MyArray(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


Public Sub Main()
    Dim tempArr() As Double
    
    For i = 0 To 10
        ReDim Preserve tempArr(i)
        tempArr(i) = i * i
    Next i   
    
    Call BubbleSort(tempArr) 'Error pops up here
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub BubbleSort(MyArray As Variant)`

Comment: BubbleSort can be sow check out this quicksort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509255/vba-bubble-sort-algorithm-slow

Comment: @BigBen  gratias tibi !

Comment: Gaudeo quod tibi profuerim :-)